# Generate a large stream for testing

Tags: java, groovy

We have a web service where we upload files and want to write an integration test for uploading a somewhat large file. The testing process needs to generate the file (I don't want to add some larger file to source control).

I'm looking to generate a stream of about 50 MB to upload. The data itself does not much matter. I tried this with an in-memory object and that was fairly easy, but I was running out of memory.

The integration tests are written in Groovy, so we can use Groovy or Java APIs to generate the data. How can we generate a random stream for uploading without keeping it in memory the whole time?

Comment: Can you simply create a mock subclass of `InputStream`?

Comment: This is an integration test, and I do need to send the data to the server. So we need some sort of data going through.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  You said you wanted a stream (by that, I assumed you meant an `InputStream`), but you don't want it tied to a specific file or in-memory thing.  So I'm suggesting writing your own implementation of `InputStream` that generates random data on demand.  Do you really mean that you want to generate a *file*?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, yes I see what you mean now. That is a good idea. At first I thought you meant to use a mocking framework.

Comment: Cool.  In that case, I've posted an answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple program which generates a 50 MB text file with random content.

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Random;


public class Test004 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("c:/test123.txt");
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i=0; i<50*1024*1024; i++){
            pw.write('a' + rnd.nextInt(10));
        }
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: I had hoped to stream the data directly from my test to my file server. This could work though.

Comment: @DavidV With some minor modification you can write to whatever stream you need (I write to a file).

Answer (score 5):

You could construct a mock/dummy implementation of `InputStream` to supply random data, and then pass that in wherever your class/library/whatever is expecting an `InputStream`.

Something like this (untested):

```
class MyDummyInputStream extends InputStream {
    private Random rn = new Random(0);

    @Override
    public byte read() { return (byte)rn.nextInt(); }
}
```

Of course, if you need to know the data (for test comparison purposes), you'll either need to save this data somewhere, or you'll need to generate *algorithmic* data (i.e. a known pattern) rather than random data.

(Of course, I'm sure you'll find existing frameworks that do all this kind of thing for you...)

Comment: Just be aware that if the random next int happens to be 255, it will cast to -1 as `byte` which means end of stream.